# What is the best way to increment these likes and checks model attributes in a callback function using an if-elif-else statement?

Tags: python, django, function, django-models, callback

I dont want to create two callback functions. I want this callback to execute in a conditional way using an if-elif-else statement.

Firstly, will the code work well as it is? So if not, what is the best way to put the house.likes and house.checks in an if-else or if-elif-else statement?

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print('Received in config')
    id = json.loads(body)
    print(id)
    
    house = House.objects.get(id=id)
    
    house.likes = house.likes + 1
    house.save()
    print('House likes increased!')
    
    house.checks = house.checks + 1
    house.save()
    print('House checks increased!')
```

I am yet to try refactoring it...still studying the code block. I don't want to break things.

Comment: house.likes += 1

Comment: @Tanveer Ahmad, I understand we can write those (>= 1, <=1, -= 1, +=1), but that's not what I am after. I am after putting the attributes, Likes and Checks, in one Callback function using the conditional statements.